# How can I add spring-security-dependency with gradle in IntelliJ?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-security, build.gradle

I would like to use the dependency:
`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'`
in my IntelliJ-project, but for any reason, it cannot resolve this dependency.

These are my dependencies. The relevant one is `spring-boot-starter-security`.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
}
```

For any reason I get this error message, when starting boot-run:

[Error-message when starting boot-run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq6tt.png)

Here the whole build.gradle-file:

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'de.hohenheim'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

bootRun {
    sourceResources(sourceSets.main)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-enable your Gradle online mode

For the latest version of IntelliJ IDE, please find an option here :

[image: IntelliJ Offline Toggle]

For older version :

1. Preferences
2. Go inside Build, Execution, Deployment.
3. Finally select Gradle.
4. uncheck offline work. Click apply then ok.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're running Gradle in offline mode. In that mode, Gradle will only use its local cache. When you add a new dependency to the project, Gradle will fail to find it. To fix this error, disable the offline mode in Intellij.

Go to the [Gradle tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/jetgradle-tool-window.html#) and disable this button:
[image: "Offline mode" button in Gradle tool window]

It should appear in the toolbar (top of the window). If it isn't visible, like in the picture below, it should appear when you make the window larger, or when you click the two arrows on the far right of the toolbar (marked in blue):
[image: Button to show hidden toolbar elements]